# What is the use of .$ in R

Tags: r

What does the .$avg signify?

```
conditional_avg <- galton_heights %>% 
                         filter(round(father) == 72) %>%
                         summarize(avg = mean(son)) %>%
                         .$avg
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `.$` is used to extract the  column `avg` as a `vector`.  Here, `.` represents the data coming from the `lhs` of the `%>%`.  It can be `vector` or `list` or `data.frame`.  In this case, it is a `data.frame` with a single column 'avg'.  We use `$` or `[[` to extract the column as a `vector`.  There is also a convenient function `pull` to do this

```
library(tidyverse)
galton_heights %>%
    filter(round(father) == 72) %>%
    summarize(avg = mean(son))  %>%     
    pull(avg)
```

---

As a reproducible example, using `data(mtcars)`, if we don't extract the 'avg' column, it will be a `data.frame` with a single column

```
mtcars %>%
   summarise(avg = mean(hp)) %>% 
   str
# 'data.frame': 1 obs. of  1 variable:
#$ avg: num 147
```

Extracting the column returns as a `vector`.

```
mtcars %>% 
     summarise(avg = mean(hp)) %>% 
     .$avg
#[1] 146.6875

mtcars %>% 
     summarise(avg = mean(hp)) %>%
     pull
#[1] 146.6875
```